# Kendo Grid do not play nice with Bootstrap dropdown or tooltips

Tags: javascript, web-applications, kendo-ui

I'm trying to use certain Bootstrap elements inside a Kendo Grid, for example Bootstrap dropdown buttons and tooltips.

The problem is the dropdown or tooltips are always positioned below the row below or above. I've tried adjusting the z-index of the displayed elements, but this doesn't fix it.

Has anyone managed to find a solution to this?

Comment: Give us code or it didn't happen. You can use http://jsbin.com

Comment: I didn't think code would be necessary, but here's a demo on jsFiddle that shows the problem: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/matbeard/gg7Yy/1/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The .btn-group class, which is the container for the dropdown-menu is positioned relatively so altering the z-index of the dropdown-menu class won't do any good.  You can position is absolutely and then adjust the positioning from there.  Something like this should get you started:

```
.k-grid-content .btn-group {
    position: absolute;
}

.k-grid-content .btn-group .btn {  
    top: -10px;
}
```

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/gg7Yy/4/) to a jsFiddle that demonstrates it in action.

Comment: That's great. Thank you. I guess I can use this to fix the issue with tooltips too.

Comment: Hmmm... looks like I was a bit premature to mark that as solved. It's fine for all except the last two rows -- they don't show unless you scroll the table down. Most users will miss that.

Comment: You might try positioning the button menus to the side of the buttons or closer to the buttons to fix that.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is to do with the Grid content being permanently set to `overflow-y: scroll` which it doesn't really need (unless you are a fixed height with the virtualization feature).

By changing the CSS of the grid content to remove the scroll bar, setting `overflow: visible` and adding extra padding to account for the missing scrollbar, it now works.

I've updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matbeard/gg7Yy/5/) to demonstrate.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, in case you have other grid cells that might contain data that will overflow into other columns with the above fix, you can set a class to the custom grid action column like so:

```
columns: [
  {
   field: "Actions", 
   title: " ", 
   filterable: false, 
   attributes: {"class": "actions-column"},
   template: <your action button template or template link here>
  }
]
```

Then in the styling for the page add the following CSS:

```
.k-grid-content tr td.actions-column {
   overflow: visible;
}
```

edit: small css selector change