# Kendo Grid do not play with Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to use certain Bootstrap elements inside a Kendo Grid, it is Bootstrap dropdown buttons.The problem is the dropdown  are always positioned below the row below or above. How can i find solution for this problem

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276417/kendo-grid-do-not-play-nice-with-bootstrap-dropdown-or-tooltips

Comment: This should also help for more generic help with using Kendo with Bootstrap http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/using-kendo-with-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kendo Grid do not play nice with Bootstrap dropdown or tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276417/kendo-grid-do-not-play-nice-with-bootstrap-dropdown-or-tooltips)